# java.security.SignatureException: object not initialized for signing

Tags: java, signature, key-pair

I'm getting the error:

> java.security.SignatureException: object not initialized for signing

at  `md.update(signature.sign())`;
 when I try to sign my signature. Basically what I'm trying to do is have some data, sign the data with my private key, save it to a file, open the file and check if the signed data is the same as the original data by comparing the two message digests that handle the data. Not really sure if that's the way it's supposed to be done, but I'm just trying different things at the moment.

According to most guides, I'm supposed to initVerify with my pubicKey, update with byte and then sign to check the data, but everytime I try to do the signing I get the exception.

```
    PublicKey publicKey;
    boolean verifyData = false;
    byte[] sign = null;
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    MessageDigest md2 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

    ObjectInputStream keyIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(publicKeyLocation)); 
    publicKey = (PublicKey)keyIn.readObject();
    keyIn.close();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataLocation+ ".txt")); 
    String data = reader.readLine(); 
    reader.close();

    ObjectInputStream signatureIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(signatureLocation)); 
    byte[] signatureToVerify = (byte[])signatureIn.readObject();
    signatureIn.close();

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withDSA");
    signature.initVerify(publicKey);

    signature.update(signatureToVerify); 

    md.update(signature.sign());
    md2.update(data.getBytes());;

    verifyData = md.digest().equals(md2.digest());

    //verifyData = signature.verify(signature.sign());

    System.out.println(verifyData);
```

Here is the verifying  class

```
    PrivateKey privateKey;


    ObjectInputStream keyIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(privateKeyLocation)); 
    privateKey = (PrivateKey)keyIn.readObject();
    keyIn.close();


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataLocation+ ".txt")); 
    String data = reader.readLine(); 
    reader.close();

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withDSA");

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA"); 
    md.update(data.getBytes()); 

    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(md.digest());


    ObjectOutputStream outSignature = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(signatureLocation)); 
    outSignature.writeObject(signature.sign());     
    outSignature.close();

    System.out.println("Finished SignHandler");
```

and this is the signature initializing signature class.

The privatekey and publickey are handled with a keypairgenerator with the algorithm "DSA" in another class and binary serialized.

Comment: If you want to sign something you should use `initSign` and not `initVerify`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/gensig.html

Comment: Sign with initSign,update,sign _and the privatekey_. Also, your 'guides' are wrong or you misunderstood them. For _RSA_ signature the verify operation (usually) does include recovering and comparing the digest, but you don't code this, it is done _by_ the Signature.verify operation (or more exactly the internal SignatureSpi.engineVerify operation). For DSA and ECDSA, the verify operation does not involve comparing digests, and in fact comparing digests is mathematically impossible.